# Vagrant box list details. How to check from which box (url) is box added to vagrant

Tags: vagrant

I have several vagrant boxes added with command `vagrant box add test_box /home/user/test.box`. Added several different boxes.

When I do `vagrant box list` I just get a name of the box and provider, but no details from where it was added/imported.

How can I check details of added boxes?

Comment: So you make your own `base box`? Why not try to open up your `Vagranfile` file and look for the line like this one...   `config.vm.box_url = "/home/user/test.box". This box's url corresponds  to your `box name` named `test_box`. In your `Vagrantfile` it should look like this... `config.vm.box = "test_box"`   Do you mean you use several `base boxes` and at the same time, several `vagrantfiles` too?

Comment: If you add box with vagrant box add, you dont need to use "config.vm.box_url" .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Emyl pointed out, right now that information is not kept around after the box has been downloaded but 1.4 will have support for that. I've sent a [Pull Request](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/pull/2327) a while ago that has been merged and will make into the next release!

Starting with 1.4.0, you should be able to find out what date the box was added and from what URL it came from with `vagrant box list -i` :)

Here's how it will look like:

```
test-box-url               (lxc)
  - url: http://bit.ly/vagrant-lxc-raring64-2013-10-23
  - downloaded_at: 2013-11-29 12:24:34 UTC
```

---

**UPDATE**: The information above is no longer applicable after the [Vagrant 1.5 release](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/commit/03b22ab9a1149581fb3adf0d13d59420a0416010) which adds support for boxes from https://atlas.hashicorp.com/

Comment: As of Vagrant 1.6.3 I am not seeing that functionality.

Comment: Looks like it [was removed on 1.5.0](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/commit/03b22ab9a1149581fb3adf0d13d59420a0416010) with the Vagrant Cloud release

Comment: This still works with vagrant 1.7.4 `vagrant box list -i`

Comment: @Red Do you have this working under a later version, 2 years on? I have version 1.9.1 and `vagrant box list -i` (with or without a box name specified) just produces the same output as `vagrant box list`

Answer (score 3):

Boxes metadata is stored under `~/.vagrant.d` directory, but such information (url from which the box has been downloaded) is not kept anywhere.

Comment: It must be kept somewhere since it checks the box for updates?

Answer (score 0):

In new Vagrant versions command not working. You should check it on file system like described here - http://sysadm.pp.ua/linux/vagrant-versioning.html

```
# Windows
PS C:\Users\Asus> cat '.\.vagrant.d\boxes\Ubuntu 16.04\metadata_url'
...
http://my-vagrant-repo.home.ua/ubuntu_16.04/ubuntu_16.04.json
...

# Linux
user@Hypervisor:~$ cat .vagrant.d/boxes/Ubuntu\ 16.04/metadata_url
...
http://my-vagrant-repo.home.ua/ubuntu_16.04/ubuntu_16.04.json
...
```

Simple script:

```
user@Hypervisor:~$ ls -1d ~/.vagrant.d/boxes/* | while read box; do printf "| %50s | %-80s |\n" "$(basename $box)" "$(cat "$box/metadata_url" 2>/dev/null)";done


|                         ansible-VAGRANTSLASH-tower | https://atlas.hashicorp.com/ansible/tower                                        |
|         box-cutter-VAGRANTSLASH-ubuntu1404-desktop | https://atlas.hashicorp.com/box-cutter/ubuntu1404-desktop                        |
|                                       cacti.0.8.8f | file:///mnt/vm/vagrant.boxes/cacti/cacti.0.8.8f.json                             |
|                                       dns_template |                                                                                  |
|                   hashicorp-VAGRANTSLASH-precise32 | https://atlas.hashicorp.com/hashicorp/precise32                                  |
|                                       ubuntu_12.04 |                                                                                  |
|                                             Ubuntu | http://vagrant-repo.ua/vagrant.boxes/ubuntu_12.04.5/ubuntu.12.04.5.json          |
|                                             ubuntu |                                                                                  |
|                                             Ubuntu | http://vagrant-repo.ua/vagrant.boxes.ag/ubuntu_16.04/ubuntu.16.04.json           |
|                        ubuntu-VAGRANTSLASH-vivid64 | https://atlas.hashicorp.com/ubuntu/vivid64                                       |
```

Hope, will help.